# Docker - Unable to make URL Requests to outside sites

Tags: django, docker, url

This is first Docker project and I am not an IT person.

I installed Docker using Django Cookiecutter.

https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html

All seems to be well until i try to do a URL request.  I assume it is some port sort of thing?

Just a simples request will not work.

response = requests.get(url)

it also appears I can not used my outside Pdf source. (DocRaptor)

Thanks.

here is the local.yml:

```
  version: '3'

  volumes:
    prelim_local_postgres_data: {}
    prelim_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

  services:
    django: &django
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
      image: prelim_local_django
      container_name: prelim_local_django
      depends_on:
        - postgres
        - redis
        - mailhog
      volumes:
        - .:/app:z
      env_file:
        - ./.envs/.local/.django
        - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      command: /start

    postgres:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
      image: prelim_production_postgres
      container_name: prelim_local_postgres
      volumes:
        - prelim_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - prelim_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
      env_file:
        - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"

    nginx-proxy:
      image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
      container_name: nginx-proxy
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
  #      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      restart: always
      depends_on:
        - django

    whoami:
      image: jwilder/whoami
      environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local

    mailhog:
      image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
      container_name: prelim_local_mailhog
      ports:
        - "8025:8025"

    redis:
      image: redis:6
      container_name: prelim_local_redis

    celeryworker:
      <<: *django
      image: prelim_local_celeryworker
      container_name: prelim_local_celeryworker
      depends_on:
        - redis
        - postgres
        - mailhog
      ports: []
      command: /start-celeryworker

    celerybeat:
      <<: *django
      image: prelim_local_celerybeat
      container_name: prelim_local_celerybeat
      depends_on:
        - redis
        - postgres
        - mailhog
      ports: []
      command: /start-celerybeat

    flower:
      <<: *django
      image: prelim_local_flower
      container_name: prelim_local_flower
      ports:
        - "5555:5555"
      command: /start-flower

    node:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./compose/local/node/Dockerfile
      image: prelim_local_node
      container_name: prelim_local_node
      depends_on:
        - django
      volumes:
        - .:/app:z
        - /app/node_modules
      command: npm run dev
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
        - "3001:3001"
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup above was fine. It was not any sort of port or URL issue.

Django Cookiecutter installs:

```
Werkzeug[watchdog]==2.2.3    # https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug
```

the "watchdog" kept interupting the URL calls.

changing to just Werkzeug==2.2.3 resolved the issue of my code being inturupted and crashing.